# null, Validation failed for query for method public abstract java.util.List

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run fetch a type jsonb field from postgreSQL in spring boot but null is not being handled, here is my query

```
@Query("select new com.rainbow.customer.rainbowcustomerservice.user.model.users.StateWiseDistrictResponse( " +
            "s.id, s.name, jsonb_agg(json_build_object( 'id', d.id, 'name', d.name, 'stateId', s.id))) " +
            "from State s " +
            "inner join District d on d.stateId.id = s.id " +
            "where (:nullToken is null or s.id in(:stateId))" +
            "group by s.id")
    Li
st<StateWiseDistrictResponse> stateWiseDistrict(List<BigInteger> stateId, String nullToken);
```

Model class is following:

```
@Data
@Builder
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class StateWiseDistrictResponse {
    private BigInteger id;
    private String name;
    @Type(type = "jsonb")
    private List<DistrictDto> districtList;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, when you try to map a value of type jsonb and its null, you might run into NPE. At least it is valid for mybatis mapping.
You need handle it via TypeHandler to support List type. Here you can find an example or I assume, you can use it directly.
[List Type handle](https://github.com/onozaty/spring-boot-sandbox/blob/master/spring-boot-mybatis-postgres/src/main/java/com/example/typehandler/ListTypeHandler.java)